# Syntax for rendering an array inside a map in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this table in my jsx file:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {
        this.state.levels.map((lvl) =>
            <tbody>
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" colSpan="2">{lvl.name}</th>
                    </tr>
                }
                {
                    this.state.subjects.map((subj) => {
                        return (subj.levelId === lvl.id &&
                            <tr key={subj.id}>
                                <td>{subj.name}</td>
                                <td>{subj.code}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </tbody>
        )
    }
</table>
```

In the block

```
this.state.subjects.map((subj)
```

each subj has a Children property. I want to iterate on the Children of each subj and render a  for it. I tried something like this:

```
this.state.subjects.map((subj) => {
    return (subj.levelId === lvl.id &&
        <tr key={subj.id}>
            <td>{subj.name}</td>
            <td>{subj.code}</td>
        </tr>

        subj.Children.map((child) => {
            return (true &&
                <tr key={child.id}>
                    <td>{child.name}</td>
                    <td>{child.code}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    )
})
```

But no additional rows are added for each Parent subject. I tried some more but they all seem to be wrong. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Are you sure `subj.levelId === lvl.id` ever returns `true`?

Comment: @ArmanCharan: Yes, because the subjects are rendered.